# Plotting water table on Python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, line

I'm trying to plot an array (a water table). The X axis are the coordinates of the map I'm working on and Y axis of my plot corresponds to the water table in that coordinate.

I'm trying the following:

```
water_table = flopy.utils.postprocessing.get_water_table(heads_data, nodata=-9999)
x = np.linspace(0, 12000, 200)
plt.plot(x, water_table.T, 'r')
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

I tried scatter plotting so that I then can add a line that passes through each point but it didn't work. I don't know if it's because is an array? How can I get rid of the blue lines under each point or add something to make my graph look "prettier"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is a water table? Can you add few data (no screenshot) to see what are your input and also do you have any figure of what the output should look like. Please read how to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

With numpy, you can filter out the zeros:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 12000, 200)
t = np.array(water_table.T)
plt.plot(x[t>0], t[t>0], 'dodgerblue')
```

Or, in case you want to have gaps where there is no data, you can replace the unwanted vales with NaNs:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 12000, 200)
t = np.array(water_table.T)
plt.plot(x, np.where(t > 0, t, np.nan), 'navy')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?